# Azure Developer CLI does not recognize environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, environment, azure-cli

On the project I am working we use azure services. When i was working on my old computer it all worked fine. 
I had to switch computer recently and i cloned the code from devops, so the code should work. I installed the Azure Developer CLI and now when I try to build the project i get the following error:
[image: Azure no developer environments found]

My code is organized in the following way and as you can see there is the .azure folder in which i have the env file (I updated the folder name now but also with the original name i  get the same error)

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Have you checked the `azd version` whether it is according to the latest releases. @Nicola Carrassi